# How to get the number of arguments required by a function

Tags: c, function, arguments

It might be impossible to do but can we actually get the number of arguments a function's wants  in C?

The goal is to make a function named `call` that requires a function's pointer and some arguments. But because we can't count the number of arguments in a variadic arguments function, I want to count how many arguments does the function's pointer requires.

Here's how I want to create it:

```
void func(int a, int b, char* c) {
    // Do things
}

int call(void *f, ...) {
    // Find how much arguments *f wants and loop over the variadic args
}

int main() {
    call(func, 1, 2, "hello");
}
```

By the way, it needs to be at run-time.

Comment: No. But C has va_start, va_args.

Comment: Is your question about getting this information at run-time, or compile time?

Comment: There are probably better ways to do what you want.  Do you have a specific use case in mind?

Comment: You also need to worry about the types of the function's parameters and possibly the function's return type.

Comment: At runtime, an executable or .dll can be programmatically loaded, and _read_, and some information describing function decoration can be determined, but this is probably beyond the scope of what you are looking for.

Comment: No, standard C has no facility for determining the number or types of arguments a function requires, given a pointer to that function (much less a pointer to `void`), nor any way of meaningfully representing that information.  An individual implementation *may* offer such a facility, but I've never seen or heard of one.

Comment: If the intent is for `call` to call your function, why not pass it the `va_list` and let it handle what parameters it needs

Comment: I want it to be used by just declaring the function and using call, no more things must be needed in the function side, just the call function.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the C standard provides a facility for ascertaining the number of arguments a function requires, other than the fact that C implementations are free to provide extensions.